# What are these things that look kind of like sprinklers in my ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, fire-sprinkler

[image: pic1][image: pic2]

What are these things coming out of my ceiling? They look kind of like sprinklers but I'm told we don't have a fire suppression system of any sort.  Are they sprinklers?  Mostly placed in the corners of rooms.  Any ideas?

Comment: Look like sprinkler heads to me...

Comment: Could be mounting base part of a ceiling mounted security camera without the camera.

Comment: Get up to look behind that "reflector" and see if it looks more like a sprinkler. You may not have a fire suppression system now, but could have before. Is this an apartment?

Comment: Yeah -- is this a single-family house, a duplex/townhome, a small apartment building (garden style/low-rise), or a high-rise apartment tower?

Comment: why did you post such crappy pictures? if you want help, post something that is a closeup.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the blurry image.  What kind of material are they made of?  Could they be speaker mounts?

Comment: Voting to close. Photos aren't good and OP hasn't been back.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The question never had enough info, it has been two years and no more info added.

Answer (score 1):

Shape, location, and wiring but not pipe strongly suggest that they are **heat detectors** - part of a fire alarm system (whether or not that's an active alarm system, you get to find out somehow.)

Modern ones tend to be "sleeker" and combined with smoke detectors, but this is a fairly common form for older ones.

They are useful for locations that have nuisance smoke but real fire potential, and also I'd guess were commonly available earlier than smoke detectors were.